# JS setDate() not working as expected when Date is created with new Date('YYYY-MM-DD')

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
let a = new Date() 
a.setDate(1) <--- this set date to the first date of this month.
```

However

```
let b = new Date ('2020-02-15')
b.setDate(1)
b.toISOString() -> returns'2020-02-02T00:00:00.000Z'
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timezones. The difference comes from the fact that you're initializing date `a` with the current time, and `b` at midnight local time, which (depending on the time of day where you are) can be a different day when represented in UTC. `setDate()` sets the "day" part of the Date object [based on your locale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate).

```js
let a = new Date() 
a.setDate(1);
let b = new Date('2022-02-14');
b.setDate(1);
console.log("UTC:")
console.log(a.toISOString());
console.log(b.toISOString());

console.log('Local timezone:')
console.log(a.toLocaleString())
console.log(b.toLocaleString())
```

The above code will stop proving its point in about a month, so for the benefit of People Of The Future™ here is the current output:

```txt
UTC:
2022-02-01T17:11:37.114Z
2022-02-02T00:00:00.000Z
Local timezone:
2/1/2022, 12:11:37 PM
2/1/2022, 7:00:00 PM
```

Comment: I was confused because I thought setDate() simply look at the 'date part' and change it to 1. So UTC didn't matter. Instead, it actually looks at the whole timestamp and setDate based on the local time zone.

Comment: That's the fun part about working with dates, yeah; timezones _always_ matter.

Answer (score 0):

I think it have something to do with your **TimeZone** and **Time Settings**

date.toISOString() always displays the date as

> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ

Where Z means UTC+0 TimeZone

try adding the the time and the TimeZone when constructing the date

something like

```
let date = new Date('2020-02-12T00:00:00.000+02:00');
```